# User function return query and insert into

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I trying to make function, that merge where `select query` return result as value(not table) and `insert into` that use value from *select statement*.
The function where argument gets from user, and this argument provide into `select` query on `table_foo` that return value `id` where I try set and use in `insert into` to diff table(`table_bar`). So I little bit confused.  Here sample of code:

```
create or replace function my_func(taskID integer)
 returns integer
 language plpgsql
as $function$
declare jobID int;
    begin
        return query (
                      select id
                      from table_foo
                       where task_id = taskID 
                      ); --that must return values such as id that i need 
         set jobID = id --trying set previosly returned value to new to use it in next statement: 
        insert into table_bar (job_id)
                    values (jobID);
    end;
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for plpgsql and no need for two queries either. Combine the INSERT and SELECT, and use RETURNING.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(taskID INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    INSERT INTO table_bar(job_id)
    SELECT  id
    FROM    table_foo
    WHERE   task_id = taskID
    RETURNING id;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try

```
create or replace function my_func(taskID integer)
 returns integer
 language plpgsql
as $function$
declare jobID int;
    begin
        select id into jobID 
        from table_foo
        where task_id = taskID;

        insert into table_bar (job_id) values (jobID);
    end;
$function$
;
```